# show that $11\nmid n^6-2n^5+4n^4-8n^3+16n^2-32n+64 $

Tags: number-theory

> Let $n$ be postive integer,show that
>   $$11\nmid n^6-2n^5+4n^4-8n^3+16n^2-32n+64 $$

I have use ugly metods to solve consider this case,$n\equiv 0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 3,\pm 4,\pm 5\pmod {11}$,have other more simple methods it?

Comment: This polynomial is $$\frac{n^7+2^7}{n+2}$$

Comment: Thanks,But then how prove can't divisible $11?$

Answer (score 3):

Starting from @Crostul's comment, we have
$$
f(n)=n^6-2n^5+4n^4-8n^3+16n^2-32n+64 = \frac{n^7+2^7}{n+2}
$$
and so $f(n)(n+2)=n^7+2^7$.
Therefore, if $11$ divides $f(n)$, then $11$ divides $n^7+2^7$.

Now $n \mapsto n^7$ is an injective map mod $11$ because $\gcd(7,\phi(11))=1$.

Therefore, if $11$ divides $f(n)$, then $n^7 \equiv -2^7 = (-2)^7 \bmod 11$ and so $n \equiv -2 \bmod 11$.

So you only have to check that $11$ does not divide $f(n)$ for $n=-2$.

Comment: You can even argue around testing $n=-2$. Note that $n \mapsto n^7$ is injective mod $11^e$ for all $e>0$, i.e. the $11$-adic valuation of $n^7+2^7$ and $n+2$ will always be the same. In particular their quotient is never divisible by $11$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $11\mid n^6-2n^5+4n^4-8n^3+16n^2-32n+64$. Then $n^7 + 2^7 = 0 (\mod 11)$ therefore $n^7 + 7 = 0 (\mod 11)$ equivalent $n^7= 4 (\mod 11)$. Using Fermat's little theorem, we get $1 = 4n^3(\mod 11) $ equivalent $3 = n^3(\mod 11)$

From $n^7= 4 (\mod 11)$ we get $9n = 4 (\mod 11) $ therefore $n=9(\mod 11) $. Now  $n^6-2n^5+4n^4-8n^3+16n^2-32n+64 (\mod 11)$ for $n=-2$ becomes $7 \cdot2^6 (\mod 11)$ which is $\ne 0 \mod 11$

Answer (score 0):

Let

$$P(n)=n^6-2n^5+4n^4-8n^3+16n^2-32n+64$$

Then $P(n+11)\equiv P(n)$ mod $11$, so if $11\mid P(n)$ for some integer $n$, then $11\mid P(n)$ for some *even* integer $n=2m$.  But $P(2m)=64(m^6-m^5+m^4-m^3+m^2-m+1)$.  If $11\mid P(2m)$, then, since $64\not\equiv0$ mod $11$, we must have

$$m^6-m^5+m^4-m^3+m^2-m+1\equiv0\mod11$$

After checking that $m=-1$ is not a solution, since

$$(-1)^6-(-1)^5+(-1)^4-(-1)^3+(-1)^2-(-1)+1=7\not\equiv0\mod11$$

we can multiply both sides by $m+1$ to get the equivalent condition

$$m^7+1\equiv0\mod11$$

or $m^7\equiv-1$ mod $11$.  Cubing both sides implies $m^{21}\equiv-1$ mod $11$.  After checking that $m=0$ is not a solution, we note that $m^{10}\equiv1$, which leads to $m\equiv-1$ mod $11$, which has already been ruled out.

Answer (score -4):

Guess $11|n^6−2n^5+4n^4−8n^3+16n^2−32n+64$, then $11|n^7+2^7$ so $n^7 \equiv-2^7 \pmod {11}.$ By Euler's theorem, $n^{10} \equiv 1 \pmod {11}$, so $n \Rightarrow n^{21} \Rightarrow (n^7) ^3 \Rightarrow -2^{21} \Rightarrow \equiv -2 \pmod {11} .$ By distributing the exponent, we have $11v(n^7+2^7) \Rightarrow 11v(n+2)+11v(7) \Rightarrow 11(n+2)$, so $(n^6−2n^5+4n^4−8n^3+16n^2−32n+64) = 11v(n^7+2^7)-11v(n+2) = 0$.

Comment: This answer is a little difficult to be read.

Comment: Please don't edit this answer, one edit is pending review so it can't be submitted.